# need help taking my key press listeners out of main

Tags: java, keypress

I have started to create a game where you can move freely. you move by using your keyboard I have it working but all I want to do is to take it out of main so I can call if multiply times from different classes. I have tried to put it in a *public static void* and call that method from main but it doesn't work.
my code is provided below. I have been stuck on this for a long time know.

I have a picture in the frame to make it visible the picture is named 1.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;
public class StartGame {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        JFrame MainFrame = new JFrame();
        MainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MainFrame.setSize(1210, 700);
        MainFrame.setLocation(new java.awt.Point(150, 30));
        MainFrame.setLayout(null);
        MainFrame.setFocusable(true);
        MainFrame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        MainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images\\sword.png").getImage());
        JLabel thing = new JLabel();
        thing.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image\\1.gif"));
        thing.setBounds(300, 300, thing.getPreferredSize().width, thing.getPreferredSize().height);

        MainFrame.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                    if (0 < thing.getY()) { 
                        thing.setLocation(thing.getX(), thing.getY() - 10);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    if (thing.getY() < 570) {
                        thing.setLocation(thing.getX(), thing.getY() + 10);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    if (thing.getX() < 1110) {
                        thing.setLocation(thing.getX()+ 10, thing.getY());
                    }
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {        
                    if (0 < thing.getX()) {
                        thing.setLocation(thing.getX() - 10, thing.getY());
                    }
                }

            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


            }
        });

        MainFrame.add(thing);
        MainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, don't use `KeyListener`, use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  Using the key bindings API will allow you to respond to key events at a "window" level, rather then a component level (if you so desire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use a game loop pattern.
The game loop pattern is a loop that process the game events in a specific order. First you processes input, update objects and last render the screen.
This image is a example of that rendering:

[image]

If you don't follow this pattern right in the beginning of your project, latter you will find more difficulties to handle.

With this pattern you can create a class Game with a method update that calls an Input handle class. With this you can move the input handle to another class that you can create. Some example:

```
class Game {

    void update(){
        InputManager.handleInput();
        updateObjects();
        render();

    }
}


class InputManager {

    void handleInput(){
        //do whatever you like

    }

}
```

Please read this blog to find more info about it: https://gamesprogramminggroup02.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/design-patterns-game-loop/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `KeyListener`, use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  Using the key bindings API will allow you to respond to key events at a "window" level, rather then a component level (if you so desire)

For example...

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class StartGame {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(1210, 700);
        mainFrame.setLocation(new java.awt.Point(150, 30));
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setFocusable(true);
        mainFrame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        mainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images\\sword.png").getImage());
        JLabel thing = new JLabel("X");
        //thing.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image\\1.gif"));
        thing.setBounds(300, 300, thing.getPreferredSize().width, thing.getPreferredSize().height);

        InputMap inputMap = thing.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = thing.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "move.up");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "move.up");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "move.down");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "move.down");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "move.left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "move.left");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "move.right");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "move.right");

        actionMap.put("move.up", new ThingAction(thing, new Point(0, -1)));
        actionMap.put("move.down", new ThingAction(thing, new Point(0, 1)));
        actionMap.put("move.left", new ThingAction(thing, new Point(-1, 0)));
        actionMap.put("move.right", new ThingAction(thing, new Point(1, 0)));

        mainFrame.add(thing);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ThingAction extends AbstractAction {
        private JLabel thing;
        private Point delta;

        public ThingAction(JLabel thing, Point delta) {
            this.thing = thing;
            this.delta = delta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            thing.setLocation(thing.getX() + delta.x, thing.getY() + delta.y);
        }
    }
}
```

This is very basic example, but it demonstrates two key points:

1. You can assign multiple keys to a single action
2. You can decouple the input (ie keyboard) from the implementation, meaning you could use the same base `Action` to handle mouse input or joy stick input

Comment: when I'm using this it doesn't show me my frame that supposed to generate. so I can't test if this works.